# UITableView in Arabic is not working

Tags: ios

I am having an issue with the header and the cellForRow in Arabic codes below.

The codes work in English.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong and resolve the problem?

Thanks.

Unfortunately I am unable to post the image due to the 10 reputation things..

e.g from the UITableView

A

B

Abha

Abu Dhabi

C

Bahrain

Beirut

D

```
- (void)setupIndexData:objects {

    self.collation = [UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation];
    NSInteger index, sectionTitleCount = [[self.collation sectionTitles] count];
    NSMutableArray *newSectionArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:sectionTitleCount];

    for (index = 0; index < sectionTitleCount; index++) {
        [newSectionArray addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
    }

    for (NSString *airportList in objects) {
        NSInteger sectionNumber = [self.collation sectionForObject:airportList collationStringSelector:@selector(city)];
        [[newSectionArray objectAtIndex:sectionNumber] addObject:airportList];
    }

    for (index = 0; index < sectionTitleCount; index++) {
        NSMutableArray *airportListArrayForSection = [newSectionArray objectAtIndex:index];
        [newSectionArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[self.collation sortedArrayFromArray:airportListArrayForSection collationStringSelector:@selector(city)]];
    }

    self.sectionArray = newSectionArray;
    [self.table reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[[self.collation sectionTitles] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSMutableArray *airportListsInSection = (self.sectionArray)[section];
    return [airportListsInSection count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [[[self.collation sectionTitles] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[self.collation sectionIndexTitles] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [self.collation sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ....
    Aiports *airportLists = (self.sectionArray)[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = airportLists.city;
}
```

Comment: Not sure is it the right way, but adding sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:) do the trick.